# Is there a way to create a function in JavaScript where, it can save 3 or more svg's or png's and play it as a gif or video?

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, gif, color-picker

I have a series of squares where, I could fill different colors to each square and save it in the background as png format. When a user clicks next, it should play the video with these series of different colored squares as preview.

Kindly help me solving this. The below JS code does not play a gif.

```
function saveSquaresAsPng() {
    // Get all square elements
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

    // Loop through squares and save as PNG
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        const square = squares[i];

        html2canvas(square).then(canvas => {
            // Convert canvas to PNG data URL
            const pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            // Create a link to download the PNG file
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = `square-${i + 1}.png`;
            link.href = `"./images/square-" + (i + 1) + ".png"`;
            link.click();
        });
    }
}

function createGif() {
    // Get all saved PNGs and add them to the gif
    const gif = new GIF({
        workers: 2,
        quality: 10,
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = `"./images/square-" + i + ".png"`;
        gif.addFrame(img);
    }

     // Render the GIF and set it as the source of the <img> tag
     gif.on('finished', function(blob) {
        const imgTag = document.getElementById("myGif");
        imgTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });

     // Render frames into an animated GIF
    gif.render();

    console.log(gif);
}
```

I expect to save the squares and play as gif.

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
function saveSquaresAsPng() {
  // Get all square elements
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

  // Loop through squares and save as PNG
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    const square = squares[i];

    html2canvas(square).then(canvas => {
      // Convert canvas to PNG data URL
      const pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      // Create a link to download the PNG file
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = `square-${i + 1}.png`;
      link.href = `./images/square-${i + 1}.png`;
      link.click();
    });
  }
}

function createGif() {
  // Get all saved PNGs and add them to the gif
  const gif = new GIF({
    workers: 2,
    quality: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  });
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = `./images/square-${i}.png`;
    img.onload = function() {
      gif.addFrame(img);
    }
  }

  // Render the GIF and set it as the source of the <img> tag
  gif.on('finished', function(blob) {
    const imgTag = document.getElementById("myGif");
    imgTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });

  // Render frames into an animated GIF
  gif.render();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the above code, at the line img.src how will it get saved? It shows an error of file not found.

Comment: @Haritha could you please give me a more clear request? maybe I can help you with another method.